# MySQL Regex ignore white space

Tags: php, mysql, regex

In my database I have a number: 00 48 76 848

The string to match against is: 004876848

I have:

```
...
WHERE tel REGEXP '\s($q)'
...
```

But that doesn't work.

What regexp do I need to achieve this?

---

```
$q = preg_replace("/[\\D]+/", "", $q);
        return DB::select('SELECT contacts_phones.id, CONCAT(firstName, " ", lastName) AS name, tel, "phoneNumber" AS type, entities.name AS company,
            entities.id AS companyId
            FROM contacts_phones, contacts, entities
            WHERE tel REGEXP "[[:space:]]"
            AND contacts_phones.contactId = contacts.id
            AND entities.id = contacts.ownerId
            AND contacts.ownerTypeId = 1
            AND contacts.archived = 0
            LIMIT ' . $limit, array('%' . $q . '%'));
```

Comment: need in mysql or PHP?

Answer (score 1):

You can't tell regex just to "ignore" whitespace. You can only match it, which is next to impossible with a value like yours.

An easier approach, without regex, would be to remove the spaces with [`REPLACE()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_replace) before you test it against your value:

```
 WHERE REPLACE(`tel`, ' ', '') = '004876848'
```

Good practice would be to normalize your values before you store them in the database. That makes everything else a lot easier.

Answer (score 0):

```
WHERE tel REGEXP '[[:space:]]';
```

Comment: That only matches one space :/

Comment: SELECT *FROM table WHERE password REGEXP '[[:space:]]';<br/> tried this using 00 48 76 848.. it should work.

Comment: How do I pass that in as a placeholder (?)? See my edit

Comment: Yes, but how do I put that into: tel REGEXP "[[:space:]]", before I have tel LIKE '%?%'